# Jquery selector [attribute] doesn't work right in IE 11

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of `<div class='input-group' style='display:none'>` that are children of a `<div id='Group'>`.

I'd like to count how many of `<div class='input-group'>`s do I have without `style='display:none'` in the list. So here is the code to get that one:

```
$("#Group div.input-group[style!='display:none']").length;
```

Works fine in Chrome. but IE returns me the whole list no matter their styles are `'display:none'` or not.

Any solutions on it?

Comment: Try `$("#Group div.input-group:visible").length;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the problem with IE 11 but there's better ways to do this

Like this:

```
$("#Group div.input-group:visible").length;
```

Or this:

```
$("#Group div.input-group").filter(function(){
   return this.style.display !== "none";
}).length;
```

Comment: Well, guess IE has its own preference... Thanks, that works

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead :

```
$(".input-group:visible").length
```

This will count only the elements without `display: none`